# MockIntegrationMessage not working when context cached

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-test

I'm working on a project using `Spring Integration 5.1.7.RELEASE`, `Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE` and `Spring Integration Test 5.0.11.RELEASE`.

As part of my tests, I'm trying to `unit test` an `IntegrationFlow` that performs calls to different `MessageHandlers`, so I'm `mocking` them using the `MockIntegrationContext` from `Spring Integration Test`.

My code is having intermittent issues on our Jenkins server that seems to be related with the context being cached. I've an integration test (`@SpringBootTest`) with no mocks and a test class specifically for the `IntegrationFlow` where `MessageHandlers` are mocked.

If the Integration Test runs before and the context is cached, the setups performed by the `MockIntegrationContext` seem to have no effect and the underlying `service-activator` is called, even when the logs show that it was unsubscribed and the mock was subscribed to the channel instead.

Here's the definition of the poller and the handle endpoint:

```java
@Configuration
public class FlowConfig {

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow fileFlow() {
          return IntegrationFlows.from(
                  Files.inboundAdapter(new File(fileDir)).autoCreateDirectory(true).preventDuplicates(false),
                      e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(pollingFrequency)).id("fileInboundSourceEndpoint").get())
                  ...
                  .handle(fileParseHandler, e -> e.id("fileParseHandlerEndpoint")) 
                  ...
                  .get()
  }
}
```

Here's the test setup:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = FlowConfig.class)
@SpringIntegrationTest
@EnableIntegration
public class FlowConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    MockIntegrationContext mockIntegrationCtx;

    @Test
    public void test_fileFlow() throws IOException {
        mockIntegrationCtx.substituteMessageHandlerFor("fileParseHandlerEndpoint",
                    MockIntegration.mockMessageHandler().handleNextAndReply(m -> m));
        new File(fileDir + "test").createNewFile();
    }
}
```

And this are two different set of logs from one unsuccessful and one successful test execution, respectively:

```
2019-09-09 15:17:02.059  INFO 14462 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {service-activator:fileParseHandlerEndpoint} as a subscriber to the 'fileFlow.channel#2' channel
2019-09-09 15:17:02.059  INFO 14462 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@51f95f0d.fileFlow.channel#2' has 0 subscriber(s).
2019-09-09 15:17:02.059  INFO 14462 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped fileParseHandlerEndpoint
2019-09-09 15:17:02.062  INFO 14462 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {message-handler:fileParseHandlerEndpoint} as a subscriber to the 'fileFlow.channel#2' channel
2019-09-09 15:17:02.062  INFO 14462 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@51f95f0d.fileFlow.channel#2' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-09-09 15:17:02.062  INFO 14462 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started fileParseHandlerEndpoint
...
2019-09-09 15:17:03.731 DEBUG 14462 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource      : Added to queue: [/tmp/file]
2019-09-09 15:17:03.732 DEBUG 14462 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/file, headers={file_originalFile=/tmp/file, id=4323b036-4edd-019e-2c61-6917c7970767, file_name=file, file_relativePath=file, timestamp=1568056623732}]
...
2019-09-09 15:17:03.732 DEBUG 14462 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'fileFlow.channel#2', message: GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/file, headers={file_originalFile=/tmp/file, errorChannel=error_channel, id=af997a89-40d6-9024-65fc-7ab3883c329b, file_name=file, file_relativePath=file, timestamp=1568056623732}]
2019-09-09 15:17:03.732 DEBUG 14462 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@7b4acdc2] (fileParseHandlerEndpoint) received message: GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/file, headers={file_originalFile=/tmp/file, errorChannel=error_channel, id=af997a89-40d6-9024-65fc-7ab3883c329b, file_name=file, file_relativePath=file, timestamp=1568056623732}]
[Fatal Error] file:1:1: Premature end of file.
```

```
13:41:05.126 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Removing {service-activator:fileParseHandlerEndpoint} as a subscriber to the 'fileFlow.channel#2' channel
13:41:05.126 [main] INFO  o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6fb365ed.fileFlow.channel#2' has 0 subscriber(s).
13:41:05.126 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - stopped fileParseHandlerEndpoint
13:41:05.128 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {message-handler:fileParseHandlerEndpoint} as a subscriber to the 'fileFlow.channel#2' channel
13:41:05.128 [main] INFO  o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6fb365ed.fileFlow.channel#2' has 1 subscriber(s).
13:41:05.128 [main] INFO  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started fileParseHandlerEndpoint
...
13:41:06.775 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource - Added to queue: [/tmp/file]
13:41:06.775 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter - Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/file, headers={file_originalFile=/tmp/file, id=3bb52d11-49ad-3ea8-eb67-7e6da721022a, file_name=file, file_relativePath=file, timestamp=1568050866775}]
...
13:41:06.788 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'fileFlow.channel#2', message: GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/file, headers={file_originalFile=/tmp/file, errorChannel=error_channel, id=ec6b0213-8109-ae43-ac27-d17b1bbad8aa, file_name=file, file_relativePath=file, timestamp=1568050866777}]
13:41:06.789 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.i.test.mock.MockMessageHandler - org.springframework.integration.test.mock.MockMessageHandler$MockitoMock$1634676946@76fb98a2 received message: GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/file, headers={file_originalFile=/tmp/file, errorChannel=error_channel, id=ec6b0213-8109-ae43-ac27-d17b1bbad8aa, file_name=file, file_relativePath=file, timestamp=1568050866777}]
```

I know there's probably a combination of `@DirtiesContext` that should fix this problem, but I'm still struggling to understand why `MockIntegrationContext` isn't able to mock `MessageHandlers` from the cached context.

Is there any way that I can fix this issue without using `@DirtiesContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when you use Spring Boot, you need to rely on its version management.
Also when you use Spring Integration as is, consider to use `spring-integration-bom` for imports. This way yo again don't need to specify version for individual modules.

My point is that you have different versions for `spring-integration-core` and `spring-integration-test`. They have to be same. Otherwise you may end up with a mess at runtime.

Now about the subject.

I don't think it is a caching problem.

You have a race condition between application context start for this test suite and that `mockIntegrationCtx.substituteMessageHandlerFor()` in the target test method.

The problem comes from the fact that you start flow from the `e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(pollingFrequency)`. This one is handled by the `TaskScheduler` on background and produces messages independently of the main thread for your test suite. That's why you observe unexpected behavior.

You can overcome the problem with something like `autoStartup` manipulation. The `@SpringIntegrationTest` has this one for you:

```
/**
 * Specify a simple matching patterns ("xxx*", "*xxx", "*xxx*" or "xxx*yyy") for
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint}
 * bean names to mark them as {@code autoStartup = false}
 * during context initialization.
 * @return the endpoints name patterns to stop during context initialization
 * @see IntegrationEndpointsInitializer
 * @see org.springframework.util.PatternMatchUtils
 */
String[] noAutoStartup() default {};
```

So, you do like this:

```
@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = "fileInboundSourceEndpoint")
```

Then in the test you autowire a channel adapter:

@Autowired
private SourcePollingChannelAdapter fileInboundSourceEndpoint;

And after `substituteMessageHandlerFor()` you start it:

```
this.fileInboundSourceEndpoint.start();
```

Comment: Thanks! This should do the trick. Quick question: I've multiple tests on the same test suite. Should I stop the SourcePollingChannelAdapter after each test and start it again only after the mocks are set?

Comment: If you use the same flow in every test method, then you indeed need to re-stop it after every test. However I would keep everything in a single test method: you have a context for the same `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` and it is better from performance perspective.